# Refine custom posts by author

Tags: custom-post-types, author-template

I want to have a way of displaying a custom post archive for a particular author. I'm able to display custom posts for a category but not just the custom posts for a author. I already have a separate author page template displaying all the posts they have written divided by post type. I'm querying this using :

```
query_posts( 
  array( 
    'post_type' => 'custom_post_name', 
    'author'=>$curauth->ID 
  ) 
); 
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Essentially I want a number of author templates pages for every author.

Comment: It isn't clear what you want. You have an author template but you also want several other author templates per author? What do these templates do? How are they different from the author template you have?

Comment: Seems like Josh want one author template for each post type. is that Josh?

Comment: M-R that is it. A general author template(which is done) and one author template per post type.

Answer (score 1):

Three steps need to be followed to accomplish it.

**1. Add rewrite rules**

```
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'author_cpt_add_rewrite_rules');
function author_cpt_add_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) 
{
  $new_rules = array( 
     'author/(.+)/(.+)' => 'index.php?author='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) .
                            '&post_type=' .$wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) );

  //​ Add the new rewrite rule into the top of the global rules array
  $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

**2. Redirect to specific templates**

```
function author_cpt_template_redirect() {
    global $wp_query;
    // check for the target request
    if (!empty($wp_query->query_vars['author']) && !empty($wp_query->query_vars['post_type'])) {
        // turn off 404 error
        $wp_query->is_404 = false;

        // include if template is available
        if(file_exists('author-'.$wp_query->query_vars['post_type'].'.php'))
            include('author-'.$wp_query->query_vars['post_type'].'.php');
        else if(file_exists('author.php'))
            include('author.php');
        else
            include('index.php');

        return;
    }

}
```

**3. Query posts to populate the page or template**

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'author_cpt_template_redirect', 1);
function query_author_cpts( $query ) {
    // check for the target request
    if (!empty($query->query_vars['author']) && !empty($query->query_vars['post_type'])) 
    {
        // query posts accordingly
        query_posts( array( 
                        'post_type' => $query->query_vars['post_type'],
                        'author_name' => $query->query_vars['author'],
                        'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) )
                    );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'query_author_cpts' );
```

Comment: Thanks M-R. I have added the code and create an author page for one of the custom post types author-custom_post.php but when I go to ?author=name&post_type=custom_post it keeps bringing back the default author.php page. Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are not you using %postname% permalink? For %postname% permalink, `http://example.com/author/admin/post` is working.. I did not tested with default permalink.

Comment: I get a page not found with that path.

Comment: you flushed the permalink? Admin->Setting->Permalink->save

Comment: that's working but still reverting to author.php rather than author-custom_post_type.php

Comment: Make sure $wp_query->query_vars['post_type'] has the same value you are using in the author template name. echo it in within the if condition of author_cpt_template_redirect function

Comment: my post-type is event I have used  $wp_query->query_vars[event'] and created a page called author-event.php. Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: what it "$wp_query->query_vars['post_type']" print?

Comment: When I print within the loop I get back 'event' the post_type

Comment: As you are not getting 404 error, I believe, "$wp_query->is_404" in function "author_cpt_template_redirect" is excuting. Statement "file_exists('author-'.$wp_query->query_vars['post_type'].'.php')" is what is not returning true. There could be couple of reasons. 1) $wp_query->query_vars['post_type'] is different what you are expecting 2) author-event.php is in a different directory. It should be in the same directory where this function exists.