# Author Pages For Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, author, author-template

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Refine custom posts by author](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76378/refine-custom-posts-by-author)

I need a way to display author archive pages for custom post types. I already know how to include custom post types into the default authors archive page that's not what I'm trying to achieve.

Example:

**By default author archive pages are like this:**

www.mysite.com/author/username

**Here's what I want:**

www.mysite.com/author/username/post-type

Whatever post type is specified at the end will display all the posts published by the author for that specific post type.

I would also like to target that specific template like this **author-{post-type}.php**

In addition I'm using the following snippet to alter the author page URL.

`function change_author_permalinks() {`

```
global $wp_rewrite;

// Change the value of the author permalink base to whatever you want here
$wp_rewrite->author_base = 'profile';

$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
```

}

add_action('init','change_author_permalinks');

However this is achieved, needs to be compatible with the above function.